# Firebase listener for field changes

Tags: firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to get notified for a Firebase Document's field change?

I have a Document in a Collection that has an array field. I want to get notified every time an item is removed from the array.

Is this possible? By the way, I'm using **[Plugin.CloudFirestore](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore)**.

Comment: Nope. Listeners fire on the document level, so when anything in the document changes, you get notified. If you need to know what changed on a more granular level, you will have to compare the old data and the new data in your application code. Alternatively, store the array data in a subcollection as separate documents, and listen for changes on that.